# Как не допустить создания дубликатов в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Предположим есть следующий класс, который символизирует таблицу в БД:

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
}
```

При создании пользователем данной сущности необходимо информировать о попытке создания дубликата.

Дубликатом считается наличие объекта в бд с такими же значениями приведенных полей

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее предпочтительным является способ проверки на дубликат средствами самой бд.

В `Entity Framework` это может выглядеть например так:

воспользуемся средствами [`fluent api`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>()
        .Property(x => x.Detail)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
            new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Operation", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>()
        .Property(x => x.Number)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
            new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Operation", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>()
        .Property(x => x.EquipmentId)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
            new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Operation", 3) { IsUnique = true }));
}
```

При помощи атрибута [`Index`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#index)

```
public class Operation
{
    [Index("IX_Operation", 1)]
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Operation", 2)]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Operation", 3)]
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
}
```

будет создан индекс на основании необходимых полей и попытка вставить дубликат выкинет исключение.

Использовать это необходимо так:
Метод добавляющий запись в бд должен быть *обернут* в блок `try`

```
try
{
    _operationService.Add(operation);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Здесь обрабатываем возникшее исключение
}
```

если же возможность изменить структуру таблицы есть но в бд уже есть дубликаты, то тогда необходимо сначала избавиться от дубликатов и потом создать индекс.

Если же по какой либо причине изменить бд(создать необходимый индекс) невозможно то тогда можно делать проверку перед вставкой в бд, но стоит помнить что такой вариант является менее эффективным(исключение составляет когда с бд работает один пользователь), так как после проверки и перед вставкой другой пользователь может добавить запись, выглядеть это может например так:

```
public static bool OperationIsExist(this IQueryable<Operation> src, Operation operation)
{
    return src
    .Where(x=>x.Detail.Equals(operation.Detail, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Where(x=>x.Number.Equals(operation.Number, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Where(x=>x.EquipmentId==operation.EquipmentId)
    .Any();
}
```

Comment: Я бы добавил что второй способ не гарантирует уникальности, т.к. проверка на существование и вставка происходят не одновременно. Кроме того, уровень изоляции по умолчанию (read committed) не позволит увидеть уже вставленные дубликаты до коммита соответствующей транзакции. поэтом второй способ стоит использовать как дополнение первого, либо дополнить дополнительной проверкой после сохранения изменений, с откатом в случае вставки дубликата.

Answer (score 1):

Создать уникальный индекс в базе данных. Железная гарантия, что дубликатов не будет, даже если в программе будет ошибка, даже если кто-то попытается забить дубликат напрямую через sql-консоль.

Comment: @Bald56rus Ну так удалите свой ответ. Какие проблемы?