# Как в entity framework сделать ограничение, чтобы email не повторялся в БД?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я хочу сделать ограничение на email, чтобы email не повторялся в БД.

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на заказы
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на покупателя
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: я хочу , что б email не повторялося в БД

Comment: Ясно. Вносите такие уточнения в тело вопроса.

Comment: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477828/179270) есть пример создание индекса через fluent-api

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [одни и те же данные в БД, entity framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981904/%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Повесьте атрибут на поле:   `[Index(IsUnique=true)]`

[Сорс](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055838/4244707)

Comment: я уже пробовал это , но выдаёт такую ошибку
The type or namespace name 'IsUnique' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) [Project_Geolab]


The type or namespace name 'IsUnique' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) [Project_Geolab]

Comment: какую именно ошибку ?

Comment: для строковых данных может потребоваться атрибут `Required` & `StringLength`

Comment: @SabaKoghuashvili значит пространство имен не подключили или сборку

Comment: @SabaKoghuashvili `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Comment: я подключил ,но все равно туже самую ошибку выдает

Comment: @SabaKoghuashvili в ef версии 6.3 все работает, какая версия у Вас?